# " Função javascript que chama funções filho"

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Fala devs blz?

seguinte, preciso da ajuda de vocês.

sou novo no js.

seguinte

eu tenho funções de js que estão no onload do body (executar automaticamente todas quando a página carrega).

porém acho que fica mt extenso poluído

minha idéia e fazer uma função pai que vai chamar todas as funções filhos

ai no body onload eu colocaria apenas uma função que iria chamar as outras.

meu site (gitpage) já ta no ar caso queiram acessar pra da uma olhada https://dannslima.github.io/danilovasconcelos/

**essas funções são para criar uma barra de status animada como na foto abaixo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
     <body onload="html() , css() , saudacao() , javascript() , bancoDados() , gitHub() , server() , ">



    > // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA DE STATUS ANIMADA 

        var progresso = new Number();
        var maximo = new Number();
        progresso = 0;
        maximo = 65;

       > // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA CSS //
        function css() {

            if ((progresso + 1) < maximo) {
                document.getElementById('pg').value = progresso;
                setTimeout("css();", 30);
                progresso++;
            }
        }
     >   // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA HTML //

        var progresso2 = new Number();
        var maximo2 = new Number();
        progresso2 = 0;
        maximo2 = 85;

        function html() {

            if ((progresso2 + 1) < maximo2) {
                document.getElementById('pg2').value = progresso2;
                setTimeout("html();", 30);
                progresso2++;
            }
        }

    >    // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA JAVASCRIPT //
        var progresso3 = new Number();
        var maximo3 = new Number();
        progresso3 = 0;
        maximo3 = 70;

        function javascript() {

            if ((progresso3 + 1) < maximo3) {
                document.getElementById('pg3').value = progresso3;
                setTimeout("javascript();", 30);
                progresso3++;
            }
        }

        // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA BANCO DE DADOS //
        var progresso4 = new Number();
        var maximo4 = new Number();
        progresso4 = 0;
        maximo4 = 65;

    >    function bancoDados() {

            if ((progresso4 + 1) < maximo4) {
                document.getElementById('pg4').value = progresso4;
                setTimeout("bancoDados();", 30);
                progresso4++;
            }
        }

     >   // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA GitHub //
        var progresso5 = new Number();
        var maximo5 = new Number();
        progresso5 = 0;
        maximo5 = 50;

        function gitHub() {

            if ((progresso5 + 1) < maximo5) {
                document.getElementById('pg5').value = progresso5;
                setTimeout("gitHub();", 30);
                progresso5++;
            }
        }


  >      // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA WINDOWS SERVER E VIRTUALIZAÇÃO //
        var progresso6 = new Number();
        var maximo6 = new Number();
        progresso6 = 0;
        maximo6 = 80;

        function server() {

            if ((progresso6 + 1) < maximo6) {
                document.getElementById('pg6').value = progresso6;
                setTimeout("server();", 30);
                progresso6++;
            }
        }

        // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA INFRAESTRUTURA E REDES //
        var progresso7 = new Number();
        var maximo7 = new Number();
        progresso7 = 0;
        maximo7 = 75;
```

Comment: Mas qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: quero montar uma função pai que irá chamar as funções filhos.

pois ali no body onload eu botaria uma única função que iria chamar as outras. acontece que tentei fazer isso mas não consegui... eu fiz assim

function pai {     

html() ; css() ; javascript();
}

mas nao deu certo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basta colocar seu código dentro de uma unica função e chamar suas outras funções dentro, por exemplo:

```
function init() {

        // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA DE STATUS ANIMADA 

        var progresso = new Number();
        var maximo = new Number();
        progresso = 0;
        maximo = 65;

        // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA CSS //
        (function css() {
            console.log("css");
            if ((progresso + 1) < maximo) {
                document.getElementById('pg').value = progresso;
                setTimeout("css();", 30);
                progresso++;
            }
        })();
        // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA HTML //

        var progresso2 = new Number();
        var maximo2 = new Number();
        progresso2 = 0;
        maximo2 = 85;

        (function html() {
            console.log('html');
            if ((progresso2 + 1) < maximo2) {
                document.getElementById('pg2').value = progresso2;
                setTimeout("html();", 30);
                progresso2++;
            }
        })();

        // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA JAVASCRIPT //
        var progresso3 = new Number();
        var maximo3 = new Number();
        progresso3 = 0;
        maximo3 = 70;

        (function javascript() {
            console.log("js");
            if ((progresso3 + 1) < maximo3) {
                document.getElementById('pg3').value = progresso3;
                setTimeout("javascript();", 30);
                progresso3++;
            }
        })();

        // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA BANCO DE DADOS //
        var progresso4 = new Number();
        var maximo4 = new Number();
        progresso4 = 0;
        maximo4 = 65;

        (function bancoDados() {
            console.log("bd");
            if ((progresso4 + 1) < maximo4) {
                document.getElementById('pg4').value = progresso4;
                setTimeout("bancoDados();", 30);
                progresso4++;
            }
        })();

        // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA GitHub //
        var progresso5 = new Number();
        var maximo5 = new Number();
        progresso5 = 0;
        maximo5 = 50;

        (function gitHub() {
            console.log('git')
            if ((progresso5 + 1) < maximo5) {
                document.getElementById('pg5').value = progresso5;
                setTimeout("gitHub();", 30);
                progresso5++;
            }
        })();


        // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA WINDOWS SERVER E VIRTUALIZAÇÃO //
        var progresso6 = new Number();
        var maximo6 = new Number();
        progresso6 = 0;
        maximo6 = 80;

        (function server() {
            console.log("OK");
            if ((progresso6 + 1) < maximo6) {
                document.getElementById('pg6').value = progresso6;
                setTimeout("server();", 30);
                progresso6++;
            }
        })();

        // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA INFRAESTRUTURA E REDES //
        var progresso7 = new Number();
        var maximo7 = new Number();
        progresso7 = 0;
        maximo7 = 75;

    }
```

você pode fazer a chamada da função logo após declara-la dessa forma:

```
(function exemplo(){
   //codigo
})();
```

com isso você só precisaria chamar a função principal

```
<body onload="init();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simples, você só precisa criar uma função e chamar as outras dentro dela. Vale destacar que você não deve utilizar `var` ao invés disso prefira utilizar `let` ou no caso de algumas variáveis, você pode utilizar `const`. Evite usar variáveis em escopos globais. E não precisa declarar o tipo com new para depois setar. Veja as variáveis.

```
<body onload="loadBars()">

    function loadBars(){
       html();
       css(); 
       saudacao();
       javascript();
       bancoDados();
       gitHub();
       server();
    }

> // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA DE STATUS ANIMADA 

    let progresso = 0
    const maximo = 65

   > // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA CSS //
    function css() {

        if ((progresso + 1) < maximo) {
            document.getElementById('pg').value = progresso;
            setTimeout("css();", 30);
            progresso++;
        }
    }
 >   // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA HTML //

    let progresso2 = 0;
    const maximo2 = 85;

    function html() {

        if ((progresso2 + 1) < maximo2) {
            document.getElementById('pg2').value = progresso2;
            setTimeout("html();", 30);
            progresso2++;
        }
    }

>    // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA JAVASCRIPT //
    let progresso3 = 0
    const maximo3 = 70

    function javascript() {

        if ((progresso3 + 1) < maximo3) {
            document.getElementById('pg3').value = progresso3;
            setTimeout("javascript();", 30);
            progresso3++;
        }
    }

    // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA BANCO DE DADOS //
    let progresso4 = 0;
    const maximo4 = 65;

>    function bancoDados() {

        if ((progresso4 + 1) < maximo4) {
            document.getElementById('pg4').value = progresso4;
            setTimeout("bancoDados();", 30);
            progresso4++;
        }
    }

 >   // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA GitHub //
    let progresso5 = 0;
    const maximo5 = 50;

    function gitHub() {

        if ((progresso5 + 1) < maximo5) {
            document.getElementById('pg5').value = progresso5;
            setTimeout("gitHub();", 30);
            progresso5++;
        }
    }


  >      // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA WINDOWS SERVER E VIRTUALIZAÇÃO
    let progresso6 = 0;
    const maximo6 = 80;

    function server() {

        if ((progresso6 + 1) < maximo6) {
            document.getElementById('pg6').value = progresso6;
            setTimeout("server();", 30);
            progresso6++;
        }
    }

    // FUNÇÃO DA BARRA INFRAESTRUTURA E REDES //
    let progresso7 = 0;
    const maximo7 = 75;
```

Answer (score -2):

GALERA ESQUEÇE TUDO.

EU ESTAVA MOSCANDO

ERA SO FAZER UMA FUNÇÃO PAI EXEMPLO

```
    function pai() {
    //botar as funções filho dentro //
    html();
    css();
    javascript();
    infra();
    }

<body onload="pai()">
```

e ja era.